# Jsp submit button image

Tags: jsp

I am using image on submit and back button.

When i click on submit , image parameter like `b1.x=66` , `b1.y =6`  along with other parameters.

how to stop sending only image parameters to send from one to other Jsp page.

Please Revert.

Code

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <i>
                    <b>Please verify the information entered , click Submit to make the payments otherwise click Back to modify details <br> <br> </b>
                </i>
                </font> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td align=middle colSpan=2> 
                <input type="image" name="b1" src="/mpt/images/submit.gif" border=0 value="success"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
                    <img src="/mpt/images/backbutton.gif" border="0" alt="Click to Edit The Information You Entered ">
                </a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's default behaviour of `<input type="image">` it will send the mouse co-ordinates, I dont think so you can prevent it. You can ignore those parameters and access the other parameters as usual.

If you really don't want those parameters you can use `<input type="submit">` and add the image as backgroung using style as follows.

```
<input type="submit" id="bi" 
    style="background-image: url("/mpt/images/submit.gif"); border: solid 0px #000000; width: 150px; height: 22px;" />
```

Adjust the height and width to fit the image.